# How do I use JavaScript to do a postback of another button

Tags: javascript, postback

I have two buttons

What I would like to do is inside button1_click() which is a javascript method, I would like to do a postback just like if btnButton2 was pressed.

I tried doing the following but it didn't seem to work.

function button1_click()
{
    __doPostBack('btnButton2','')

}

and whilst that refreshed the page, it never went through to the btnButton2_Click trigger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it with UniqueID

```
function button1_click() {
    __doPostBack('<%= btnButton2.UniqueID %>','')
}
```

Comment: You can use this with any .NET control that postsback including DropDownLists and TextBoxes

Comment: just wondering, how would the postback know that the button was pressed? Is there like a default event for each type of .NET control that the postback will fire during postbacks?

Comment: The first parameter to the method __doPostBack is the name of the button.

Comment: yep i gathered that, but i'm just curious cos chprpipr says that you can also do it for numerous other .net controls too. so say for a dropdownlist, how does it know whether you're calling back based on a OnTextChanged or OnIndexChanged?

Answer (score 2):

From recollection, this worked for me:

```
function button1_click() {
    document.getElementById('<%= btnButton2.UniqueID %>').click();
}
```

Comment: This will work if your button is a real `<input type="button" />` and not a link button.  If you do have link buttons, you can create a hidden button wired up to the same event handler and call `.click()` on the hidden button.

Comment: this worked for me in both asp:Button and asp:ImageButton. Thanks a lot!